# disabled swap mem, how to enable again?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, fstab

I ran `sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab sudo swapoff -a`

which resulted in no swap memory being used, down from 2 gigabytes. (I have 24 gigabytes of ram).

`/etc/fstab`

```
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=0446af6d-0bd1-4811-91e7-7663019eecad /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=343C-7C17  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -alh /swapfile`. You have a /swapfile identified in /etc/fstab, but it's commented out... maybe because the /swapfile doesn't exist... hence my `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

comment in the out-commented swap-related line in /etc/fstab:

```
sed -i '/ swap / s/^#\(.*\)$/\1/g' /etc/fstab
```

then enable swap again:

```
swapon -a -v
```

Option -v tell you more about, whether or not the operation was succesfully